# CONTAINS match on CONCAT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, concatenation

Sorry if this seems like rambling I'm not typically a DB person just trying to work through an issue.

I have two tables `cases` and `legal_entity` the data on the two tables looks like this

`legal_entity`

| first_name | last_name | address_1_zip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Maria | Munoz | 33122 |
| John | Glenn | 10003 |
| Melissa | Johnson | 90210 |

`cases`

| style | case_number | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Munoz, Maria | SL12345 | 2021-03-01 11:45:26.657 |
| Glenn, John | SL45678 | 2021-03-02 12:10:14.552 |
| Johnson, Melissa (DNY) | SG42561 | 2021-04-10 01:06:10.214 |

What I am trying to do is combine the `last_name` and `first_name` fields from the `legal_entity` table with a comma between them, and match (contains) it against the `style` field in the `cases` table. For everything in the last month basically. This is the query I'm using

```
SELECT
    C.[case_number]     AS CaseNumber,
    C.[style]           AS FullName,
    LE.[first_name]     AS FirstName,
    LE.[last_name]      AS LastName,
    LE.[address_1_zip]  AS ZipCode,
    CONCAT_WS(',', last_name,first_name) AS CombinedName
FROM
    CPSQL.dbo.legal_entity AS LE
INNER JOIN CPSQL.dbo.cases as C ON CONCAT_WS(', ', LE.last_name,LE.first_name) LIKE C.style
WHERE C.create_date >= Convert(datetime, '2021-03-01') AND C.create_date <= Convert(datetime, '2021-04-16')
ORDER BY C.create_date
```

The issue I run into is that for cases where `C.style` contains more information than just LastName,FirstName

(Ex. `Johnson, Melissa (DNY)`)

It doesn't match/join even if you change the = to LIKE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Full working query

```
SELECT
    C.[case_number]     AS CaseNumber,
    C.[style]           AS FullName,
    LE.[first_name]     AS FirstName,
    LE.[last_name]      AS LastName,
    LE.[address_1_zip]  AS ZipCode,
    CONCAT(LE.last_name,', ',LE.first_name, '%') AS CombinedName
FROM CPSQL.dbo.legal_entity AS LE
JOIN CPSQL.dbo.cases as C ON 
           C.style LIKE CONCAT(LE.last_name,', ',LE.first_name, '%')
WHERE C.create_date >= Convert(datetime, '2021-03-01') AND C.create_date <= Convert(datetime, '2021-04-16')
ORDER BY C.create_date
```

Comment: CONCAT_WS introduced in sql server 2017 , why you tagged 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add wildcard:

```
FROM CPSQL.dbo.legal_entity AS LE
JOIN CPSQL.dbo.cases as C ON 
           C.style LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(', ', LE.last_name,LE.first_name), '%')
```

---

```
FROM CPSQL.dbo.legal_entity AS LE
JOIN CPSQL.dbo.cases as C ON 
           C.style LIKE CONCAT(LE.last_name,', ',LE.first_name, '%')
```

Comment: This doesn't error out but I'm at 5 minutes on the query and it's still not finished (takes approximately 2 seconds without the wildcard.) Is something wrong here or is the wildcard search just not the way to go about linking these two tables?

Comment: @Cistoran I guess it's because it is no longer "equi"join with 2 functions attached. Let's try to simplify it a bit

Comment: That simplified version works perfectly. Edited the OP with the working query in full. Thank you SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

You are already using the operator `LIKE`, but without any wildcards it is equivalent to `=`.
Use wildcards:

```
ON C.style LIKE CONCAT_WS(', ', LE.last_name, LE.first_name) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an addition condition statement using the LEN

```
LEN(CONCAT_WS(',', last_name,first_name)) = LEN(C.style)
```

Comment: LEN() returns an INT which will never equal C.style